# Unable to plot multiple lines in pine script

Tags: pine-script

Please check below code, this is only plotting 2 lines not others.

[image]

```
//@version=5
indicator("Levels by tintin",overlay=true)

pc = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D" , close[2], gaps = barmerge.gaps_off,    
        lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)


R= pc + 0.25
S= pc - 0.25


R1=math.pow(R,2)
R2=math.pow(R1,2)
R3=math.pow(R2,2)
R4=math.pow(R3,2)
R5=math.pow(R4,2)
R6=math.pow(R5,2)
R7=math.pow(R6,2)
R8=math.pow(R7,2)

S1=math.pow(S,2)    
S2=math.pow(S1,2)
S3=math.pow(S2,2)
S4=math.pow(S3,2)
S5=math.pow(S4,2)
S6=math.pow(S5,2)
S7=math.pow(S6,2)
S8=math.pow(S7,2)


plot (R1, color = color.blue)
plot (R2, color = color.blue)
plot (R3, color = color.blue)
plot (R4, color = color.blue)
plot (R5, color = color.blue)
plot (R6, color = color.blue)
plot (R7, color = color.blue)
plot (R8, color = color.blue)



plot (S1, color=color.red)
plot (S2, color=color.red)
plot (S3, color=color.red)
plot (S4, color=color.red)
plot (S5, color=color.red)
plot (S6, color=color.red)
plot (S7, color=color.red)
plot (S8, color=color.red)
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It does plot everything and you can see their values but those numbers are out of your chart's scale. Use the auto scaling and you will that they are there.

[image]